# Converting from batch to shell

Tags: linux, bash, batch-file

I have a set of batch commands that I'm trying to convert to shell so I can use them on my linux environment. The command should read

```
rcontrib -y  < view\inside_NE.rays -o result/%%04d_inside
```

In windows (using batch), running this command should produce a set of files that are numbered like this:

`0001_inside.hdr`  `0002_inside.hdr`  etc.

However, when I ran this command in bash, I expected to get eight files with names that start with 0001 to 0008 but I got only one file which was named 0001_inside. How would I do this in bash? 
Please note: rcontrib is a command that is part of a package that runs on both linux and windows

If you like this question please vote up.

Comment: That is not a valid `bash` command. Show us the equivalent command in Linux that you are trying

Comment: I updated my post to explain the confusion. rcontrib is a command that is part of a package that runs on both windows cmd and linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think %%04d is to escape '%' in DOS, your rcontrib program probably wants %04d like in c syntax to name the file with a 4 digit integer.  In bash you don't need to escape it, have you try this?

```
rcontrib -y  < view/inside_NE.rays -o result/%04d_inside
```